# SQL: Calculate Q4-to-date vs Q3-same-period % change

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

Task: calculate the % change in today's Q4 data (October 1st to 26-Nov Q4) 
...versus same period in Q3 (1 July to 26-Aug Q3).

This is the output table I'm looking for.

[image]

As each day progresses, the SQL code must compare the current data to the same day the previous quarter.

So far a poster has given me this, which is really helpful.

```
DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)
```

So now I want something like...

```
SELECT sales 
FROM Sales_Database
WHERE date between '2018-06-01' and DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)
```

...but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for Correlated Subqueries. If still struggling; Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you should be able to use :

```
DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)
```

This will substract one quarter from the current date.

Comment: This is great but not quite what I want. The date needs to be January 1st 2018 - to DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER). At the moment it's picking up all historical data.

Comment: Ok, then : MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER will give you the start date of the current quarter

Comment: This is not working for me I'm afraid. Even if it did, I'm not sure how to apply this as a filter. I need Q4-to-date data in one column, then the same period in Q3 in another column.